# Paypal Checkout - Payment always on pending

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, checkout

Since three days i am trying to get the Paypal Checkout to work but i always have the problem that the order is created and the money in gone from the buying account but not reaching the payee account.
So here is my setup:

**The Smart Buttons integeration in JavaScript:**

```
paypal.Buttons({
  
  env: enviroment,
  
  // Set up the transaction
  createOrder: function() {

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('bookingId', bookingId);

    return fetch (url_createOrder, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
      return res.result.id;
    });
  },

  // Finalize the transaction
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    console.log(data);
    
    // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
      console.log(details);
      // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer
      // window.location.href = 'danke.php';
    });
  }

}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

As you can see the **createOrder starts a AJAX call to this script:**

```
[...]
$client = new PayPalHttpClient($environment);

$request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
$request->prefer('return=representation');
$request->body = self::buildRequestBody($price);
// 3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
$response = $client->execute($request);
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// 4. Return a successful response to the client.
return $response;
}

private static function buildRequestBody($price) {
 return array(
   'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
   'application_context' => array(
      'brand_name' => 'Example',
        'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost/example/abbruch.php',
        'return_url' => 'http://localhost/example/danke.php'
      ),
      'purchase_units' => array(
        0 => array(
          'reference_id' => 'example_addr',
          'description' => 'example Address',
          'amount' => array(
            'currency_code' => 'EUR',
            'value' => $price
          )
        )
      )
    );
[...]
```

Everything works so far to this point. I get a OrderId back which i return to the AJAX call and then i am am able to insert credentials and pay the given price.

When i finish the payment the onApprove of the smart buttons in the JS file get called back and i also get the correct **response of that actions.order.capture()**:

```
{create_time: "2020-08-14T19:37:59Z", update_time: "2020-08-14T19:38:20Z", id: "6FP46164U47878440", intent: "CAPTURE", status: "COMPLETED", …}
create_time: "2020-08-14T19:37:59Z"
id: "6FP46164U47878440"
intent: "CAPTURE"
links: [{…}]
payer:
address:
country_code: "DE"
__proto__: Object
email_address: "sb-ughwh2901918@personal.example.com"
name: {given_name: "John", surname: "Doe"}
payer_id: "8Z5RM2ERW6VTL"
__proto__: Object
purchase_units: [{…}]
status: "COMPLETED"
update_time: "2020-08-14T19:38:20Z"
__proto__: Object
```

Afterwards the money is gone from the buyer account but it says "pending", here a screenshot (but in german)
[payment_is_pending.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9767R.png)

On the seller account i can´t select anything like "approve". I found an example of the paypal checkout api which works similar and tried to copy it into my code but yeah... same story.
Then i thought maybe the problem is the seller sandbox account, but if i try it which an sandbox account created and given by a paypal tutorial is says pending as well.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payments are pending because there is no sandbox account with the email sb-2xact2876961@business.example.com **confirmed**, so the payments are in an unclaimed state. Pending unclaimed payments will be automatically returned after 30 days if left unclaimed.

To claim the payments, the email sb-2xact2876961@business.example.com must be confirmed on a sandbox account, via https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email and https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications/