# PayPal api for server payment from application account to seller

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have an eCommerce website.
I integrated PayPal checkout buttons, so they make the payment to my business account
which I approve on the server. (Nodejs)
(by the way, I only see the funds come off the personal account but not added to the business account)

Now I want to transfer those funds (from my account) to the actual seller.
Couldn't find any API for doing so. everything I see involves a buyer that needs to approve on the client-side.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the issue of funds not being added to the business account, ensure the business account's email is confirmed in sandbox: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63420245/2069605

If you require that your business account receive the funds first, and then forward them to another account, you will need a Payouts integration. Using Payouts in the live environment requires business approval from PayPal. Here is information about requesting that approval: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts

If you want to skip the payment entering your account and have it proceed directly from the buyer to the final destination, then instead of using Payouts you can set a custom payee during the initial checkout: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

Comment: Using the Payouts API takes an additional commission. this is not good.
Can I see the transactions made between buyers and sellers in y app without transferring the money to my account in between?

Comment: If you use a custom payee integration, you can't see anything about the resulting transactions in your account. You can save the result of the API operations so you know what happened, but once it happens it's out of your hands, and you are not responsible for it as it is between 2 other parties.